# Need to fix Errors pointed out by HTML checker

Tags: html

```
<div class="needContent">
                    <label for="Country" >Country</label>  //ERROR
                    <span class="red-star">&lowast;</span>
                    <input list="browsers" name="Country" required="required">
                    <datalist id="browsers">
                        <option value="Canada">
                        <option value="The United States">
                        <option value="India">
                        <option value="JPakistan">
                        <option value="Germany">
                    </datalist>
                </div>
```

Error: The for attribute of the label element must refer to a non-hidden form control.

From line 96, column 6; to line 96, column 27

nt">↩                   Countr

```
<div class="needContent">
                    <label for="Province" >Province</label>
                    <span class="red-star">&lowast;</span>
                    <select name="Province" id="Province" onkeyup="starShow()"
                     required="required">
                     <option value="">Alberta</option>
                     <option value="">British Columbia</option>
                     <option value="">Manitoba</option>
                     <option value="">New Brunswick</option>
                     <option value="">Newfoundland and Labrador</option>
                     <option value="">Nova Scotia</option>
                     <option value="">Ontario</option>
                     <option value="">Prince Edward Island</option>
                     <option value="">Quebec</option>
                     <option value="">Saskatchewan</option>
                     <option value="">Northwest Territories</option>
                     <option value="">Nunavut</option>
                     <option value="">Yukon</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
```

So according to my assignment I am supposed to create

Dropdown list: select element with options - the 10 provinces and 3 territories of Canada, required. The full names of provinces and territories will be showed up on the list and organized in two groups: Provinces and Territories. The values for option elements must use standard 2-letter abbreviations.

but if I put the (value ="ON") it gives me errors in HTML checker. Can someone help me fix it please?

Comment: The `for` attribute of a label element has to match the `ID` attribute of another element, not the `name` attribute.